# Vue.js two different main Layouts

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vue-router

I am using vue.js version 2.5.13 installed with the vue-cli using the webpack-template.

Now I would like to use the generated App.vue-template for all my public pages and another template AdminApp.vue for all my admin-routes.

My router/index.js is like this:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Router from 'vue-router'
import LandingPage from '@/components/LandingPage'
import AdminDashboard from '@/components/admin/AdminDashboard'

Vue.use(Router);

export default new Router({
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/',
      name: 'LandingPage',
      component: LandingPage
    },{
      path: '/admin/dashboard ',
      name: 'AdminDashboard',
      component: AdminDashboard
    }
}
```

My main.js is like this:

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import App from './App.vue';
import AdminApp from './AdminApp.vue';
import router from './router';
    
if (window.location.href.includes('/admin/')) {
  new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    router,
    components: {AdminApp},
    template: '<AdminApp/>'
  });
} else {
  new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    router,
    components: {App},
    template: '<App/>'
  });
}
```

Now if I go to `localhost:8080/#/` and then via url to `localhost:8080/#/admin/dashboard` the admin-panel does not use the AdminApp.vue-Template but the App.vue-Template. If I refresh this page, it works.

Do you know why? Are there some best practices for using two or more different templates for different routes?

Comment: Can you demonstrate same on a fiddle? or share your repo?

Comment: Is `main.js` being executed every time the route changes, or only when a real page load happens?

Comment: You're doing it wrong, no need to have 2 vue instances depending on the path, Vue router takes care of that for you. Let me try to create an example for you following your code.

Comment: Here, this will give you an idea how you should do things https://jsfiddle.net/o4dup5gu/10/

Comment: Great! That really solved my problem! Thank you!

Comment: Thank you @Craig, I had the same problem and this helps me in 2020.

Answer (score 0):

**In Brief:**

You should make your layouts.For example layout1 & layout2.
Then you should define them as global component in your main.js and finally use them with v-if in your app.vue depends on your condition.

**With Detail:**

first in router/index.js:

```
    {
    path: '/',
    name: 'Home',
    component: Home
  },
  {
    path: '/auth/login',
    name: 'login',
    meta:{layout:"auth"},
    component: Login
  },
```

which first route will render with `admin layout` and second one render with `Auth layout` for example.
Now in `main.js` we will define layouts as component:

```
import Admin from './Layouts/Admin.vue'
import Auth from './Layouts/Auth.vue'
Vue.component('Admin',Admin);
Vue.component('Auth',Auth);
```

Then in App.vue we check meta datas that passed from routes to detect which layout needs:

```
   <Auth v-if="this.$route.meta.layout==='auth'"/>
   <Admin v-if="this.$route.meta.layout==null"/>
```

Ok.All thins done!

Now we have two layout.